# Get selected text of a dropdown's item and split by new line and then show alert result using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Get selected text of a dropdown's item and split by new line and then show alert result using jQuery

Sample dropdown's item

```
Value   Text
1       AAA
2       BBBB
3       CCCCC
```

Get the currently selected text:

```
var selectedItemText = $("#dropDownId option:selected").text();
// Get AAABBBBCCCCC
```

Show alert result

```
alert(selectedItemText);
// Show "AAABBBBCCCCC"
// But I want "AAA\nBBBB\nCCCCC" How to split selectedItemText by new line?
```

I'm sorry for less information, I change Text from "A" to "AAA", "B" to "BBBB" and "C" to "CCCCC".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
alert(selectedItemValue.split('').join('\n'));
```

### Update

```js
$('#dropDownId').change(function(){
var results="";
$('#dropDownId :selected').each(function(index, sel){ 
   results+= $(sel).text()+'\n'; 
});

alert(results);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropDownId" multiple="multiple" name="multiple">
  <option value=""> -- Select -- </option>
  <option value="1">AAA</option>
  <option value="2">BBB</option>
  <option value="3">CCC</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: I'm sorry for less information, I change Text from "A" to "AAA", "B" to "BBBB" and "C" to "CCCCC".

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var str = "";
$("#dropDownId option:selected").each(function () {
        str += $(this).text() + "\n";
      });
});
alert(str);
```

Comment: I'm sorry for less information, I change Text from "A" to "AAA", "B" to "BBBB" and "C" to "CCCCC".

Answer (score 0):

Try This:
alert("selectedItemValue\n");

Comment: I'm sorry for less information, I change Text from "A" to "AAA", "B" to "BBBB" and "C" to "CCCCC".